# .Net (C#) - How to rename list (sheet) using google sheets api v4?

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have to copy existing sheet and rename it. And I cannot find any info how to rename the sheet via Google sheets API v4.
For now I have:

```
    var defaultSheet = service.Spreadsheets
            .Get(spreadsheetKey)
            .Execute().Sheets
            .First(x => x.Properties.Title.Equals("Default sheet"));
    var newSheet = Service.Spreadsheets.Sheets.CopyTo(
            new CopySheetToAnotherSpreadsheetRequest { DestinationSpreadsheetId = spreadsheetKey },
            spreadsheetKey,
            (int)defaultSheet.Properties.SheetId);
```

I hope anyone has any idea how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does [`UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest) help?

Comment: The above request may be used in conjunction with [`batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) api call.

Comment: yep, I used it, but `batchUpdate` expected another input model. And I cannot find way how to include `UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest` into `batchUpdate` method.

Comment: Does adding this json `{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateSpreadsheetProperties": {
        "properties": {
          "title": "NewSheetName"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}` in request body for post help?

Comment: Thank you **shahkalpesh**! I've found solution using `Request` class. Added it into the question.

Comment: Please add the solution as an *answer* rather than putting it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution (how to copy sheet with specified name):

```
    var defSheet = Service.Spreadsheets.Get(baseUrl).Execute().Sheets.First(x => x.Properties.Title.Equals("OldSheet"));
    var newSheet = new Request
    {
        DuplicateSheet = new DuplicateSheetRequest
        {
            SourceSheetId = defSheet.Properties.SheetId,
            NewSheetName = "NewSheet",
            InsertSheetIndex = 1
        }
   };
   var y = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest { Requests = new List<Request> { newSheet } };
   Service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(y, baseUrl).Execute();
```